# Symfony2 JMS serializer add custom property

Tags: symfony, serialization

As the title states, I am trying to add a custom property to the serialized object I return.

Let's take a User with the following methods:

- getFirstname, setFirstname
- getLastname, setLastname
- getUsername, setUsername
- ...

Now in the serialization I would like to add a property fullName: Firstname + Lastname.

I have a getter method in my entity like so:

```
/**
 * get name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->getFirstname()." ".$this->getLastname();
}
```

My serialization file looks something like this:

```
AppBundle\Entity\User:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    properties:
        id:
            expose: false
        username:
            expose: true
            groups: [list, details]
        email:
            expose: true
            groups: [details]
        name:
            expose: true
            groups: [list, details]
```

I have tried with

```
    name:
        expose: true
        groups: [list, details]
        access_type: public_method
        type: string
        serialized_name: fullName
        accessor:
            getter: getName
```

and other variants but I can't seem to get it right.

`Note: Yes I've cleared my cache and tried it again.`

Anyone able to tell me what I am missing ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your full name is not a property at all you have to define a virtual property:

```
AppBundle\Entity\User:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    properties:
        # All properties but not name
    virtual_properties:
        getName:
            groups: [list, details]
            serialized_name: fullName
```